# Turn and point Animation not ending in correct position

Tags: unity, c#, animation, character

I have *Right Turn, Point* & *talk* **[Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/)** animation. I am playing animation in this order

1. Play Idle animation
2. **Turn** animation
3. Point Animation
4. Then, run **Turn** animation again with - speed to bring it back(reverse)
5. and then finally played Idle animation and loop continue.

[image]

But the problem is, each time when I return from step 4 my character rotation is different. And over different iterations the character rotation become completely changed. The rotation of the character increment in each iteration. How can I solve this problem? I am learning [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) but unable to understand.

Comment: Have you thoroughly checked through your animations to see if they change the y-axis at any point?

Comment: Turn animation will obviously change the Y axis. It changing.

Comment: Oh so when it turns back, it turns more than you wanted? Then it is not caused by the animation but something else I think.

Comment: "Oh so when it turns back, it turns more than you wanted?" Yes, exactly. FYI! There is no code yet

Comment: You said you were learning Root Motion? Did you check `Apply Root Motion` in the Animator Component?

Comment: Yes Yes, it is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68692/discussion-between-voon-van-eustace-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).

Comment: To make it easier for people to help, please include a screenshot of your settings in the Animation Clip Inspector.